# Question regarding Google Guice's TypeLiteral

Tags: guice

I have a few question regarding use of TypeLiteral.

First I understand that you need to use TypeLiteral whenever you want to bind instance with generic information. If you want to inject Box< String > you need to bind `bind(new TypeLiteral<Box<String>>(){}).to(BoxImpl.class)` so when you encounter `@Inject Box<String>` we inject instance `BoxImpl`.
My question is:

1. Why are we creating the new instance of TypeLiteral whenever we need to bind it?
   (we usually bind(interface.class).to(implementation.class)
2. What is the purpose of **{}** when creating the new instance of TypeLiteral when binding? `new TypeLiteral< Box< String > >(){}` <--
   What is the purpose and how is this used to help the binding process?
3. Why do we need TypeLiteral to begin with?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not strictly necessary to create a new instance each time, it's just generally more convenient to do that than to store the `TypeLiteral` instance as a constant somewhere and use that.
2. You're creating an anonymous subclass of `TypeLiteral<Box<String>>`. By doing so, the specific generic type arguments are fixed for the whole *class* you're creating and as such available at run time.
3. Because otherwise it would be impossible to differentiate between a `Box<String>` binding and a different `Box<Integer>` binding.

By the way, for the example you gave I think you'd need to write:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Box<String>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<BoxImpl<String>>(){});
```

(Unless `BoxImpl` implements `Box<String>` itself for some reason, as opposed to `Box<T>`.)